# Skype Connectivity Issues on Ubuntu 13.10 x64

Tags: 13.10, connection

I went through almost every Skype-related thread here and google. I am running Ubuntu 13.10 x64 on HP Pavilion 15-b107eo. Although I managed to properly (i guess) install skype, I face connectivity issues. Although my connection is a bit unstable (mobile broadband) my connection drops regularly when I am on video call. Calling back again as soon as it reconnects doesn't work since it cannot establish a new call or I get strange noises when I manage to reach the other person. So my only solution is to close skype and start it again. Although my connection is unreliable, I didn't have such issues with my previous OS (Windows 8) and only happens when on Skype video call. Sometimes I get the apport window to report the problem but I don't have the crash report line at hand. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I experience also problem with Skype. The latest version of Skype 4.2 for Ubuntu linux is on Precise 12.04 LTS. At first I had problem with installing it.
I tried dynamic version of Skype instead.

So as far as I know there exist only two versions of Skype for Ubuntu. 
  This dynamic one has also some issues like it beeps when you send as message as I have new Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

There is now Skype 4.3 that works for Ubuntu 13.10 as well.
Link to question:
[How to install Skype 4.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Comment: 4.3 works like a charm! Thanks a lot!