# How to install Skype 4.3?

Tags: software-installation, skype

***Note: The legacy Skype for Linux application (v4.*) is now discontinued and was removed from Canonical’s partner repositories, so this question and its answers are obsolete. Please refer to [a newer answer](/a/932189/175814) of our [canonical Skype installation question](/q/7498/175814).***

Skype 4.3 is just released with considerable improvements. As a regular Skype user I want to use the latest Skype on my Ubuntu 14.04, but there is no updates from Update Manager. Even in Skype website only Skype 4.3 is available only for Ubuntu 12.04. Is there anyway to use this latest Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 or how much we have to wait for the update?

Comment: You already got a couple of howto answers. Just wanted to add that there is a wishlist bug about updating the Canonical Partner repository: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1280109 Please feel free to mark that it affects you, and maybe add a comment. ;)

Comment: The version of Skype available in the Canonical Partner Repository is [now updated](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-skype-linux-4-3-ubuntu-software-center).

Comment: just want to say that installing this version of skype solved the "cannot sign problems" for version 4.2 on linux...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Answer (score 236, accepted):

#### Step 1: Remove previous version.

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

#### It is Important if you installed older version of Skype on your Ubuntu, Clear the old Skype folder before installing latest version. Then clear that by using:

```
rm -rf ~/.Skype
```

#### Step 2: Preparing to Installing Skype.

- Users of 64-bit Ubuntu, should enable [MultiArch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) if it isn't already enabled by running the command

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  ```
- Update repositories and "updates" list:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Optional, install `GDebi` (see below):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdebi #(read Why you need to install gdebi...)
  ```

#### Step 3: Installing Skype

**Method 1: Download and install from file**

```
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

**Method 2: Install Skype from [Canonical Partner Repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Canonical_Partner_Repositories)**

So add the Canonical Partner Repository to "updates" list by following the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then install Skype via the [Software-Center](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareCenterFAQ) or via the Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype)

---

**Why you need to install gdebi instead of using dpkg or Ubuntu software center.**

**dpkg** (for Debian package) is a software tool from the command line is responsible for installing, creating, deleting, and managing Debian (packets deb), the type of packets processed by Ubuntu. It also allows the Debian package management from sources outside the apt repositories.

To install packages, `dpkg` has a graphical interface, `gdebi` , you can use if you prefer to avoid the command line.

**gdebi** is an application installation and management of Debian (.deb) packages. This is a utility that works both in graphic mode console and allow the installation of packages outside of APT deposits : from a website, CD-ROM, portable media, etc. 
It has the same functionality as `apt-get` or `Ubuntu Software Center` : it ensures that the package to be installed is compatible with the version and architecture of the Ubuntu system in which you try to install it, and also ensures that all dependencies required by the package are satisfied. Otherwise, the dependencies are downloaded from the Internet. Using tabs, `gdebi` also provides access to important information such as folder paths in which to install the various files from .deb package.

Finally `gdebi` is a lightweight deb packages installer which was the default in Ubuntu Desktop. Now Ubuntu uses Ubuntu Software Center which is slow and sometimes you get `The package is of bad quality` error.

---

#### Read more about `GDebi`:

To install a package you have downloaded from a website, rather than from a software repository. These packages are called .deb files. Because they may have been created for a different Linux distribution, you might find that there's dependency issues with Ubuntu, meaning that they may be uninstallable.

`gdebi` is a simple tool to install .deb files. It has a graphical user interface but can also be used in your terminal. It lets you install local deb packages **resolving and installing its dependencies.. It automatically checks packages for their dependencies and will try to download them from the Ubuntu software repositories if possible**. You may first need to install `gdebi` - simply install the `gdebi` package using one of the package managers like `dkpg`, `Synaptic` or open a Terminal and type `sudo apt-get install gdebi`.
Once you have installed `gdebi`, use the File Browser to find the package you want to install.

Double-click the package to open it with `gdebi`. If all dependencies have been met for the selected package, simply click the `Install package` button to install it. `gdebi` **will warn you if there are unmet dependencies, which means that there's dependencies that aren't resolved in the repositories that you're using.**

Comment: I did overwrite something, which one shouldn't. `apt-get install -f -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" libqtwebkit4:i386` and it fixed the installation error I was receiving due to dependency issue.

Comment: Why the need to install `gdebi`? The Ubuntu Software Center or `dpkg -i`, both of which are already installed, can handle .deb file installations.

Comment: @KasiyA I still don't see why you would *need* to install gdebi. Your answer simply reads like "it's more comfortable than dpkg and faster than Software Center". That may be true, but it's personal preference. You make it sound like gdebi is essential for running Skype 4.3.

Comment: This gave me error on my 12.04 x64 installation: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, but the rest worked just fine.

Comment: Error: `dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture`. I said already that my installation is 12.04 x64: `x86_64`. Btw, `dpkg` version is 1.16.1.2.

Comment: I can't do `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` - I get unmet dependencies `libdbusmenu-qt2:i386` and `libqtgui4:i386` which I can't seem to get installed for one reason or another.

Comment: +1 Step 2 & 3 worked fine for me thank you (no previous Skype install). Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit.

Comment: FYI this will also create the popular taskbar skype icon for easy access, while the "normal" installation via Ubuntu software center will not.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove gdebi`

Comment: I get "E: Unable to locate package sni-qt" on the first step.

Comment: throw error `Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~)` while install .deb file

Comment: I can see I have upvoted the weenie comments on why you need `gdebi`? I didn't and I faced a [dependency hell in a fresh installation!?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/832739/skype-for-mama-doesnt-work). Just install the damn thing, install Skype and then remove `gdebi`, by `sudo apt-get autoremove gdebi`. Thank you wise author of this answer - so little did I knew...

Answer (score 60):

## Install From Ubuntu Software Center

As of August 2, 2014, you can now install Skype 4.3 directly from the Ubuntu Software Center.

To do this, you must first enable the Canonical Partner Repository, using the following steps (based on steps provided by OMG! Ubuntu; see [source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-skype-linux-4-3-ubuntu-software-center)):

> - Search for and open ‘Software Sources’ or 'Software & Updates' in the Unity Dash
> - Select the ‘Other Software’ tab
> - Check/tick the boxes next to the two entries headed ‘Canonical Partners’
> - Exit, and hit ‘Ok’ on the software reload prompt

Then search for Skype in the Ubuntu Software Center and install it as you would any other software.

([Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-skype-linux-4-3-ubuntu-software-center))

## Install From Skype's Website

You can download the latest version of Skype as a .deb package [directly from its website](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/?intcmp=blogs-_-generic-click-_-skype-4-3-for-linux). Choose the 12.04 (multiarch) version if you're running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or newer; it'll still work if you're on i.e. 14.04 LTS, because that's just what Microsoft lists as the minimum Ubuntu version.

Once you have it, run the following commands to ensure your system is clear of any previous installations:

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
```

Then double-click on the downloaded .deb file to open it in the Ubuntu Software Center and install it like any other software.

Afterwards, also run the following command in the terminal to ensure that support for the indicator menu is available:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Now you can find Skype in the dash, run it and enjoy it!

*(Source: [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/skype-43-for-linux-released-with.html))*

Comment: Is "Software Sources" searchable from the Dash? I would have said: Press Alt+F2 and run the command software-properties-gtk

Comment: Indeed, on Ubuntu 14.04 it appears that the option you really want is "Software & Updates" (though that query does bring it up as an option). Updating answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok; actually I had (for some unknown reason) a local desktop file with "NoDisplay=true", so I didn't see it in the Dash at all. Just removed that file. Sorry for the noise. ;)

Comment: After installing using any of the method above, you may see Skype crashes after logging in.
For that you need to drop ~/.Skype and then login. It will be perfect.

Comment: @WarriorIng64, did you install this way or simply copy paste? software center does not find skype even after including canonical partners.  installing from microsoft's site (skype) does not work (MICROSOFT NOT WORKING PROPERLY?  TYPICAL!!!!) for 14.04.  even after removing all traces of skype, the deb package reinstalls 4.2

Comment: @tonygil I haven't tried installing 4.3 from the Software Center, but I have successfully installed Skype 4.3 on multiple Ubuntu computers using the latter method. Please make sure you have the latest version of the .deb file.

Comment: i had downloaded the latest deb from the site itself.  apparently, COMPLETELY deleting the previous skype install was a necessary step.  i did multiple things here and there until eventually it worked.    anyway, thanks UPVOTED :)

Comment: AFTER I went through this and it worked, then my daily software update check ran and tried to uninstall skype 4.2 (it must have loaded my list of current packages while I was doing this upgrade). It then told me there's no need to remove 4.2 because it doesn't exist. So perhaps a normal Ubuntu package update will take care of this for others.