# Skype 4.3 in repositories

Tags: updates, skype, repository

Why is not the recent Skype version 4.3 for Linux available in the partner repository? When will it come there? As far as I know, software installation via repositories is preferred over installation of standalone packages.

Comment: If you want Skype 4.3 see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Comment: Should probably point out that Skype and Microsoft produce their own installable `.deb` packages on the Skype site, if you realllly need an expedient update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Launchpad bug https://launchpad.net/bugs/1280109 includes as much as there is of an answer to your question. Please feel free to add a comment to that bug report.

Comment: So it seems to depend on Microsoft rather than Canonical. I will try to push it forward there. Thank you!