# Problem with dialog windows and different workspaces

Tags: unity, compiz, google-chrome, workspaces, bug-reporting

I have 9 workspaces. Usually Google Chrome is on 1-st workspace. But sometimes open new window of Google Chrome on some other workspace, let say 3-rd. Then I click something that will open new Dialog Window (in Google Chrome), while working on 3-rd workspace, this new Dialog Windows will appear on 1-st workspace. And I don't know about it. I keep clicking a few times and then I realize that all new windows are opened in 1-st workspace.

I can easy reproduce this doing this steps:

- Open Google Chrome
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, to open new Window
- Move this 2-nd Windows to another workspace
- Open gmail.com in this 2-nd Window, and compose new email.
- Press attach [image]
- **New Attach Dialog will open in 1-st workspace, while I'm waiting it in 2-nd.**

**I just realized that it is no matter on which workspace Google Chrome is located, Dialog Window always appear on first workspace**.

**Is this bug of Ubuntu or Google Chrome?** I want to report a bug, but don't know who is bugging

```
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 36.0.1985.125 
$ uname -srv
Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: Did you try with firefox or chromium or other browsers? if this problem happens just in google-chrome, so there is a bug in the chrome and not Ubuntu itself.

Comment: @KasiyA there is no such problem in `firefox` or `chromium`. Thanks for this tip

Comment: then there is a bug on google-chrome, please report it as a bug :) and delete your question to get back your 150 rep ;) no 145rep

Comment: @KasiyA. May be this question will help to someone else to understand that he is not alone. Also I share a link to this question in a bug report.

Comment: @KasiyA if you move your first comment to answer, I will be able to accept answer and give bounty to you

Comment: feel free to edit answer and include the reported bug link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was just [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502433/problem-with-dialog-windows-and-different-workspaces?noredirect=1#comment752767_502433) but I post it as an answer may be it will help to someone else if he/she is looking for same issue.

According to my comment OP checked `firefox` and `chromium`. He reply that there is no such a problem in other browsers except `google-chrome` with version `36.0.1985.125`. So it is not a bug related to Ubuntu and the bug is on `google-chrome` with above version.

This is still a problem in Google Chrome `Version 38.0.2125.122 (64-bit)`

Comment: Kasiya, does this bug affects you? Did you check it?

Comment: I don't have google-chrome install on my system. I use chromium and firefox sometimes but I can test it if you give a google-chrome downlaod link ;)

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/. Execute this `sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome` before install `*.deb` file. This will prevent adding Google's repository to package manager.

Comment: Ok I'm downloading now I will reply the result

Comment: @c0rp I test that but it does not effect me chrome Version 38.0.2125.122 (64-bit). but I installed via `sudo gdebi /path/to/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and I didn't execute `sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome`. try to remove and install again with `gdebi` installer, it's very useful .deb package installer. see more about that [under my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3/488062#488062). and also my kernel version is `Linux 3.13.0-37-generic`