# Can't install Skype 4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: apt, 64-bit, dpkg, skype

First of all, I think this question is not duplicated, because I have tried all other solutions I found here, but nothing solved my problem.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

I have tried until now:
`sudo apt-get install skype` -> It didn't work. The error was:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried `sudo dpkg add-architecture && sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb` but it didn't work either. The error was:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
Package libqt4-dbus is not installed.
skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
Package libqt4-network:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
Package libqt4-xml:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1); however:
Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
Package libqtgui4:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
skype depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1); however:
Package libstdc++6:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libx11-6; however:
Package libx11-6:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libxext6; however:
Package libxext6:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libxss1; however:
Package libxss1:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on libxv1; however:
Package libxv1:i386 is not installed.
skype depends on
dpkg: error processing package skype (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
skype
```

I have tried to use after `sudo apt-get -f install` but it didn't solve the issue.

I have tried to install by using `Gdebi`. The error was:

```
Cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386'
```

I have tried to install using **Ubuntu Software Center**. The error was:

```
Cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386'
```

I have tried changing the server in "Software and Updates". I have tried to use "Main Server" and "Servers for United States". But it couldn't solve my problem.

Anyone has any idea how to solve that?

**SOLVED**

Well, I formatted my pc and I installed Skype first of all. Probably another installation that I had done before the Skype installation was the problem, i guess.

Thanks people!

Comment: Try adding the Partner Repos and then try installing the Skype you downloaded again. Might help it find the skype-bin package.

Comment: Unfortunately my partner repos had been added already.

Comment: I am facing the same issue (Elementary OS: Ubuntu 14.04) and have pretty much every way; but unfortunately I can't afford to format the PC to install Skype. Guess I'll rather try to convince the people on the other end use an alternative like Hangout.

Comment: This question is not "solved" by a new installation of the complete OS. I have the same problem on 16.04. Something I try to install messed the multiarch up so it is now somehow trapped. It is not understandable for me why I am not able to simply purge anything not usefull and do a fresh install of skype then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Skype 4.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Answer (score 32):

I'm running 14.04 64bit, here is how I installed.

Downloaded skype 4.3 from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64), and I used Gdebi, to install it, and it installed fine.  if you don't have Gdebi installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

[image]

As I said, I haven't had any issuses using the method Stated above.  Another thing that you can do to fix broken packages, you can do

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

OR

Go to synaptic package manager if you have it installed, go to Edit --> Fix broken Packages.

An alternate way to install it, is

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

After this if you get any error like cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386' or some other package, try this command.

```
     sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

It will suggest you to try the following command.

```
    sudo apt-get -f install
```

After executing the above command, try the following one once again.

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

For more details, see the official Skype forum [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux-archive/Unable-to-install-Skype-update-4-2-0-13-on-Ubuntu-12-04/m-p/3043638#M3795).

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: As I said in my post, I have tried to use Gdebi, but I had the error: Cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386'.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but unfortunately I have tried these other 2 ways to install, but both show me the same error: Cannot install 'libqtwebkit4:i386'.

Comment: Install libqtwebkit4:i386 by launchpad didn't solve the problem, because, apparently, it has other dependencies. When I tried to install, I got the error "Cannot install 'libqt4-opengl:i386'".
:(

Comment: try the following steps! It worked on debian 7 , ubuntu 14.04 and ubuntu 14.10

    1) dpkg -i skype-install.deb 

now you will get some list of errors

    2) dpkg --add-architecture i386

    3) sudo apt-get update
    
    4) sudo apt-get -f install --fix-missing 

    5) dpkg -i skype-install.deb 

whoo! it works :-)

Comment: Works for me on xubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: Doesn't work. Neither on Ubuntu 14.04 or Elementary OS Freya (both 64 bit).

Comment: Followed the provided steps; but still ending up with `skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13).`

Comment: btw, the skype that is downloaded from that link is not 64bit rather a 32bit version of skype.

Comment: Just an F.Y.I, there is no 64bit skype, only 32bit.  See [Here](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/64-bit-linux-version/td-p/991578).

Comment: This did something but it still `skype:i386 depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13)`. I am using 16.04

Comment: @Ben  Try this:  `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, `apt-get -f install`, `apt-get install libqtwebkit4:i386`, `rm -rf ~/.Skype`, and the reinstall Skype.

Comment: thanks, but that folder does noes not even exist, so deleting it does nothing. and installing libqtwebkit4:i386 does not work because it depends on other packages that do not get installed.

Answer (score 4):

First run :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to install the deps related with the OS 14.04LST 64 bit  and then try below commands ... skype 4.3 installs perfectly

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

It worked for me .... ;;;; :)

Answer (score 2):

Running the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: When I do this using trusty 14.04, I get `E: Unable to locate package skype`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this exact same problem by enabling "Recommended Updates (trusty updates)" in the "Software & Updates" control panel, "Updates" tab.

Comment: This is the perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem istalling Skype 4.3 on Ubuntu 13.10. However when following the instructions above, Skype 4.2 always ket showing up, even when removing skype before downloading the newer version. In order for it to work, I had to remove the .Skype configuration file in my home directory:

```
rm -r ~/.Skype
```

Don't worry, you will not loose your contacts or anything else. The only slightest annoyance that I can see that *at first* some of your contacts will show up with their skype name and not the familiar full name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've got the same problem out of not following the RTFM principle :)
Installed some packages from xorg-edgers and then haven't removed them properly as it is said in the installation comment (i.e. just removed the repository but not the installed packages). This caused a domino effect which lead apt to be unable to install any i386-library dependent packages...

I've found it by trying installing packages with aptitude which verbose directly the issues (different versions of 64-bit packages). Then I've added back the xorg-edgers repository and removed it properly with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

Hope it will help somebody...

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to version **4.3.0.37** because version **4.2.0.13** was not allowing me to login anymore with the error **“Can’t connect”**.

Unfortunately for me after hours of trying I could not get pulseaudio to work on my system, only ALSA is working so I downgraded back to **4.2.0.13**

To solve the login error I spoofed the version number **4.2.0.13** to the latest **4.3.0.37** version and login was working again, problem solved.

So to solve your problem simply downgrade back to **4.2.0.13** and spoof to **4.3.0.37** version, exit Skype and run this command:

`sudo sed -i "s/\x34\x2E\x32\x2E\x30\x2E\x31\x33/\x34\x2E\x33\x2E\x30\x2E\x33\x37/g" /usr/bin/skype`

After you should be able to login as normal.

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried all the above but are still struggling (like I was):

The problem might only be the server you use for your Ubuntu update (it was in my case). The server I was using did not had the right definition of `libqtwebkit4:i386`.

To solve that:

- Open System Settings
- Software & Updates
- Ubuntu Software tab
- Download from (Other... and select Best server)

Update your system with `sudo apt-get update` and then:

```
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

Worked for me.