# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS: problem with Skype

Tags: skype

eventually I have made the decision to get rid of windows and go for ubuntu!!
I had been thinking to do so for long time, but I was keeping putting it off.
So, I am excited, but I have also started to hit the first issues :).

I now have a problem with skype, and that's why I am writing.

My ubuntu version is the following:

```
davide@Gis74:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I installed skype a couple of weeks ago and it had worked fine until this morning.
Since this morning I can no longer connect to it and I have been getting the following notification:

**An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Unknown Error: '' ("The cache has no package named 'skype-bin'")' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies**

I did some research without too much luck.
I am posting some of the commands output I seem to understand can be useful to debug the issue:

```
davide@Gis74:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 26 not to upgrade.


davide@Gis74:~$ sudo apt-cache policy 'skype*:*'
skype:
  Installed: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Version table:
     4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
 *** 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
skype4pidgin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype-mid:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
pidgin-skype-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20130613+svn660+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     20130613+svn660+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
skype-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
empathy-skype:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20130613+svn660+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     20130613+svn660+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
pidgin-skype:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20130613+svn660+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     20130613+svn660+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
pidgin-skype-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20130613+svn660+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     20130613+svn660+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

I was thinking to re-install/upgrade skype but I am not sure how to do it.
Can anyone please help?

Many thanks,
Davide

Comment: See if this http://askubuntu.com/questions/504689/cant-install-skype-4-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit/504693#504693, helps.

Comment: Hi @Mitch, that was helpful, i ran the commands sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get upgrade and that has solved the issue. I don't understand though how a new version of an application can screw up an already installed one. Obviously I am missing something :). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 15):

Skype 4.2 no longer works because Microsoft want everyone to upgrade to the latest version. **This is Ubuntu version independent - it will affect you if you have 12.04 or 14.04.**

<sub>Taken from [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-skype-linux-4-3-ubuntu-software-center) on OMG Ubuntu</sub>

> Older versions of Skype will stop working; they won't be able to sign into ...the service.
>
> Why? Microsoft says they “…want everyone to experience the best Skype has to offer – from enhanced quality to better reliability to improved security – and the newest version of Skype is the way to do that.”

It is quite hard to keep support for older systems for a long time - it limits development.

[Here is the latest](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb) (4.3) release. It says it is for 12.04, but it works fine on 14.04

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Skype 4.3 is also available from the partner repository...

Comment: Thank you very much. recently while loggin skype it keep saying: `skype can't connect`. So i thought my computer is banned from using skype. and i installed googlehangout for the similar purpose. but now your answer solved my problem. i first uninstalled skype: `sudo apt-get remove skype`, then downloaded the package from the link in your answer. then double click it. It got installed. Thank god everything is working fine now. I am running `lubuntu 13.09`