# How to get rid off the Skype error "Skype can't connect." on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, skype

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my machine since long. I installed "Skype 4.2 for Linux". It was working fine till yesterday night. But today when I tried to log-in to skype I'm not able to do it. An error message "Skype can't connect." is displaying when I press Sign in button after filling the Skype Name and Password. I'm damn sure about the Skype Name and Password I'm entering are correct. I tried with the same credentials on a machine running on Windows 7. I was able to log-in over there.

To resolve this issue I tried almost everything, from removing Skype completely to install Skype again and again from 'Ubuntu Software Center', 'By downloading latest Skype .deb file and running it on my machine', 'Disabled the firewall', etc. but every time the result is same.

For your information I'm also attaching the screen shot of the error message to this question.
[image]
So can some one help me in this regard please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/505977/186134 Is the answer you're after.

Comment: @Tim:But I'm not using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I'm still using 12.04 LTS only and the skype was working fine till yesterday night. Then how can it stop working suddenly without giving me any update notification?

Comment: Still applies. See the linked article in that answer.

Comment: Latest release: http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb

Comment: @Tim:I've kept it for download. What should I do after the download finishes?

Comment: First run `sudo apt-get remove skype` in terminal. Then click on it and it will open in the software centre. Click install, as if it was an app from there, not a download :)

Comment: @Tim: As you said I run the command sudo apt-get remove skype into terminal. Then I openend the downloaded file skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb but it's giving me the error as "Conflicts with the installed package 'skype-bin:i386'". Now what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16155/discussion-between-tim-and-phplover).

Comment: Skype 4.3 is also available from the partner repository, so you don't need to remove the Skype package, just update it with Update Manager.

Comment: Use `$ sudo apt-get autoremove skype` for better cleanup :P

Comment: Had the same problem. Updating to 4.3 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-skype-linux-4-3-ubuntu-software-center)

> Older versions of Skype will stop working; they won’t be able to sign
>   into ...the service.
>
> Why? Microsoft says they “…want everyone to experience the best Skype has to offer – from enhanced quality to better reliability to
>   improved security – and the newest version of Skype is the way to do
>   that.”

That's the reason you're facing such problem. Don't worry the latest Skype 4.3 is now available in the Ubuntu Partner repository, so just install the update and you'll be fine.

Comment: Just be aware that from Skype (for Linux) from version 4.3 requires *pulseaudio*, so you may be able to sign in, but your mic and sound  might stop working, depending on your individual setup.