# Skype sign in: Server Connect Failed

Tags: 12.04, skype

When I try signing in to skype , I get the message "Sign in Failed - Server Connect Failed". To resolve this issue I tried almost everything, from removing Skype completely to install Skype again and again from 'Ubuntu Software Center', downloading the latest Skype .deb file and running it on my machine, etc. but every time the result is the same.My Ubuntu version is 12.04.Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505810/ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-problem-with-skype/505977#505977

Comment: Make sure you are running Skype 4.3+. It this doesn't help, try removing the .Skype folder from home.

Comment: I second what @ToDo says. I also experienced this issue a day or two ago. The problem was that I was still using Skype 4.2. After a `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, I was using Skype 4.3, and could connect again. However, Skype would always crash after a few seconds or so. After removing my `~/.Skype` folder, I was fine again. The downside of it is that I lost my earlier conversation logs :-/ Ah, how greatly Microsoft improved my Skype experience...!

Comment: I've the same problem since yesterday... I thinks its a skype problem....

Comment: According to [@tim's answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/505810/ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-problem-with-skype/505977#505977) so install new one [How to install skype 4.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Comment: Skype is now up to 5.1 for linux -- and once again, "server connect failed" is code for "you are not running the current version".

Answer (score 2):

Download the Skype Installation Package (a Debian package) from the Skype website http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ and install that on your computer. I install it with GDEBI PACKAGE INSTALLER.  Hope it works!

Comment: Why GDEBI not the software centre?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am running Skype 2.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit.

I fixed it simply by typing

```
sudo mv ~/.Skype ~/.Skype.old
```

After restarting Skype, I could login as usual.

Comment: @priya, you should click the tick below the down arrow to accept the answer, and show it worked.

Comment: this did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by the following steps :

using commands below

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
apt-get autoremove
```

Downloading `skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb` [from Skype download site](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb) or
Installing Skype from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: +1 this worked for me. Stupid that other people probably didnt even try this and downvoted it. The "accepted" answer actually didn't work for me, this did.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: when I try to log in manually, I get the same "Server Connect Failed" error. However, **when I automatically sign in, it logs in perfectly (thanks to a backup of my .Skype folder).**

(Tested on Fedora Core with Skype 4.2 & Xubuntu 10.04 with Skype 4.0)

Update: **logging in with a stored password no longer works.** Microsoft is making it impossible for older skype versions to function.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to version **4.3.0.37** because version **4.2.0.13** was not allowing me to login anymore with the error **“Can’t connect”**.

Unfortunately for me after hours of trying I could not get pulseaudio to work on my system and as ALSA support is dropped in **4.3.0.37** I downgraded back to **4.2.0.13**

To solve the login error I spoofed the version number **4.2.0.13** to the latest **4.3.0.37** version and login was working again, problem solved.

So to solve any problems simply install **4.2.0.13** and spoof to **4.3.0.37** version, exit Skype and run this command:

`sudo sed -i ‘s/\x34\x2E\x32\x2E\x30\x2E\x31\x33/\x34\x2E\x33\x2E\x30\x2E\x33\x37/g’ /usr/bin/skype`

Answer (score 0):

`rm -r ~/.Skype` worked for me with ubuntu 13/ skype 4.3

Comment: Add to your answer how that command helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also did everything as it was said above. I removed a previous version 4.2.0.11 of Skype in the terminal by typing:

**sudo apt-get remove skype

apt-get autoremove**

Then I installed the downloaded package ***skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb*** from the site http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ for my Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx using *"Gdebi Package Installer"*.
 That's it. The new Skype works as usual.