# PulseAudio Manager gives the error Connection failure: Connection refused

Tags: 10.04, pulseaudio, skype, connection

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and recently had to upgrade to PulseAudio due to Skype not working with ALSA. However it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried the following

[Why am I getting this "Connection to PulseAudio failed" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error) -- i.e. full uninstall and reinstall

I don't know much about PulseAudio and what it's supposed to be. So please can somebody help me with the different commands that I can use to debug this further?

Finally will an upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you have 10.04, you don't have the latest version of the Skype client, right?

Comment: I had to update skype to latest version since the previous version stopped working (I believe from Aug 1st). The default skype that comes with 10.04 is very old and no longer works. I'm ok even if the solution involves upgrading Skype to a version that will work without needing PulseAudio to be setup. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/507139/skype-sign-in-server-connect-failed

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that it was possible to even install the latest Skype on 10.04. But please note that the desktop packages of Ubuntu 10.04 are no longer supported. Probably you'd solve the issue by upgrading the Ubuntu version. There are many good reasons besides Skype to do so. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing Ubuntu 14.04 from scratch. An update to Ubuntu 12.04 completely ended up screwing things up