# how do i get latest skype on my machine?

Tags: skype

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.
and im trying to installe latest skype version.

All the time it gets me 4.2 version and i cant connect to my account. I have read that some time ago 4.2 cannot conect.

And i cant it update to 4.3

Any Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Skype 4.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download and install the latest version from skypes homepage. Just download and double click the .deb file. Then follow the instructions. You may need to remove the old skype version with sudo apt-get purge skype

http://www.skype.com/de/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/504689/cant-install-skype-4-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit

thnx to u.
and finaly got 4.3 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit [bug #1372846](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1372846). I see that you solved the problem by installing directly from the Skype website. Another solution (workaround) would probably have been:

```
sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin
```