# I can't install Skype on my Ubuntu Computer (15.04)

Tags: apt, software-installation, skype, 15.04

I was trying to install Skype, but everytime I can't connect to an IP-address. My wifi is fine, my computer as well. I don't know what it could be. Presently I am using Ubuntu [15.04] version and am new to this environment. Kindly fix this problem.

It says:

```
missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/main amd64 Packages 
missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/restricted amd64 Packages missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/main i386 Packages 
missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/restricted i386 Packages
```

Comment: Please, describe more detailed what you do, and what IP address you are talking about.

Comment: Im trying to install skype, then I have to update the repository sources and the it fails while connecting to connect to 188.64.17. Im from germany and he cant connect to the repository sources so it isnt able to pdate them

Comment: Im sorry this is the IP address 188.64.17.1

Comment: Skype support 32 bit only. What about your system . ? Did you installed a 32 bit distro . ?  Enter `uname -a` in the terminal and paste the output

Comment: Linux lars-thinkpad-t410 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You are using a 64 bit distro. . here is the link `http://askubuntu.com/questions/504689/cant-install-skype-4-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit` which may solve your problem

Comment: No it doesn't. I already made it and the error is still there. He is trying to update the repositories.

Comment: Couldn't you just install Skype through the Canonical Partners repository instead of installing the official deb?

Comment: first remove missing cd/rom issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom   and then try to install http://tipsonubuntu.com/2015/03/24/install-skype-4-3-in-ubuntu-15-04/

Comment: It doesn't worked. I read its maybe a mistake of my source list?

Comment: Read my answer and give me a comment with @A.B. - Wir können dann auch deutsch sprechen.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you need to comment (using #) or remove a few lines at the top of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I'm talking about lines which start with

```
deb cdrom:
```

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Could you make your answer a bit more detail?

Comment: @A.B.: What else is there to say? The OP will let us know if he doesn't know how to edit a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message:

```
missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/main amd64 Packages missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/restricted amd64 Packages missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/main i386 Packages missing cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet - Release amd64 (20150422) vivid/restricted i386 Packages
```

Open a terminal with Ctrl+Shift+T

Open the file `sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add a `#` at the beginning of each line starts with `deb cdrom`, like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Alpha amd64 (20150316)]/ vivid main multiverse restricted universe
```

Save with Ctrl+O (O wie Otto) and exit with Ctrl-X

After this run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install Skype with:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```