# Unable to install Skype despite following earlier thread(s)

Tags: skype

I have been bashing my head against a wall with this one; despite having trawled several relevant threads and asked in freenode, I'm still stuck.

The following thread is the closest to my issue:
[Can't install Skype 4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504689/cant-install-skype-4-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit)

Gave a 14.04 64-bit system to my dad but haven't been able to get skype running for him. The libqtwebkit4 one is given as the problem, but it is already installed - I've checked. I've also run all of the instructions in the linked thread to no avail. Partner repositories are enabled, but I can't install from apt-get either.

```
nothing@computer:/home/Shared$ sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
Selecting previously unselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 234518 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skype-install.deb ...
Unpacking skype (4.3.0.37-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13).

dpkg: error processing package skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
nothing@computer:/home/Shared$
```

Halp?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install -f` to install missing dependencies. How do you know libqtwebkit4 is installed?

Comment: Already did that, it removes the package without errors, but I'm still unable to install, I get the same libqtwebkit error.

I know libqtwebkit4 is installed because if I try to install it the response 'libqtwebkit4 is already the newest version'.

Comment: Where did you get that `skype-install.deb` file? The best way to install Skype on Ubuntu is to enable Canonical Partners and then install it the usual way, which on the command line would be: `sudo apt install skype` (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner)

Comment: As in the linked thread I got it via "wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb", but I have also tried with "sudo apt-get install skype" to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @user339367: Did you enable Canonical Partners? What if you run: `sudo apt install skype skype-bin` (try apt instead of apt-get, somtimes it's 'smarter')