# Skype can't connect

Tags: skype

After I restarted my computer to finish a upgrade, I could not log in at Skype anymore.

It only shows the message:

> Skype can't connect.

If I try web version it works. I'm using Skype 4.2.

Comment: Try again, Skype is working now.

Comment: I just tried, the problem remains.

Comment: The post about 4.2 being retired is probably the most correct. However, I'm on 4.2.0.13 and for whatever reason, it still works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Skype 4.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

According to [this post](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Having-trouble-signing-in-Retirement-of-older-versions-of-Skype/td-p/3439685), skype versions older than 4.3 are unable to connect as of today (2014-08-01).  Though it could have just been a temporary outage of the skype servers, I was able to connect after updating skype.

Comment: I just updated to 4.3 following this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3

and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Typical Microsoft.

Comment: This [link](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-skype-4-3-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-pinguy-os-elementary-os-lxle-and-other-ubuntu-derivative-systems/) explains the instructions for installing Skype 4.3 on a lot of distros including Ubuntu 12.04 till 14.04 for both 32bit and 64 bit systems.

Comment: Skype isn't updated since for Linux, Thanks Microsoft.

Answer (score 27):

First get rid of the old skype from repo:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

Second, delete your ~/.Skype folder

```
rm -R ~/.Skype
```

Then download skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb from [http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/?intcmp=blogs-*-generic-click-*-skype-4-3-for-linux](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/?intcmp=blogs-_-generic-click-_-skype-4-3-for-linux) and execute it as a deb package:

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: a `sudo apt-get -f install` may be required if your system a bit broken like mine did. i blame this i386 architecture thingie.

Comment: at the end you can see that Purge Anarchy is usefull

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the problem is that Skype 4.2 is no longer available. The solution is to install a fresh version of Skype 4.3 which is already available for users.

Here is what to do :

**Step 1: Remove the old version of Skype (4.2 or older)**

```
cd ~ && rm -r .Skype    
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

**Step 2: Install Skype version 4.3**

**For 32-bit Operating Systems:** follow these steps

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

**For 64-bit Operating Systems:** follow these steps

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

That's it. Happy Skyping :-)

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution, worked in my Ubuntu 14.04,
Just:

1. Open “Software & Updates” and enable Canonical partners repository under Other Software tab.
2. In the terminal do: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install skype

here the [Source!](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/skype-4-3-install-in-ubuntu-1404/)

Have a Grate day!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy workaround if you need to use Skype older than 4.3:

1- Install Skype 4.3.0.37, launch it, tick the "log me in automatically" box and log in. Exit (and end the process if still active)

2- Download Skype 4.2.0.11 deb package from https://launchpad.net/skype.  Don't install it but extract the "Skype" binary file under /usr/bin

3- replace the /usr/bin/skype file with the 4.2.0.11 version (you'll need root privileges)

4- start skype and it will log in automatically

Hope this solution will last because some webcams or products (Asus SV1T for examples) are only compatible with old versions of Skype!

Answer (score 0):

It is not your machine problem. Skype servers are down. This is not country specific.

I would like to add an official report, but Skype support is horrible.

**UPDATE:** it seems that Skype decided to shutdown the sopport for old versions (lower than 4.2). Update your client to be able use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to call and receive calls from people using skype 4.3 for linux: the message error was *Unable to connect*

Removed skype installed from repository

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

and installed skype beta

https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04

Comment: skype no longer supports 4.3.

Answer (score -1):

actually(and I discovered this quite randomly) the icon atop the desktop, displays the skype icon....which turns out to be the problem.  I kept getting the same error message as you guys were getting, even after installing the latest version of Skype(4.3)  But I had forgotten to quit Skype using that icon up there!  After doing that, Skype performed flawlessly once more!  I hope this helps someone.

Comment: incidentally, after performing that action, Skype no longer displays an icon up there as it did with version 4.2 (just so you know what to expect)  Google for a way to put the icon back up there, as 4.3 comes from Skype and not from our repositories.  Another afternoon wasted(I wasn't doing anything anyway, right?)

Comment: As regards the icon, it works just as with 4.2, i.e. it needs the package sni-qt:i386. That package should have been installed automatically, unless you intentionally asked to not install recommended packages.

Comment: yes, thank you Gunnar, although I did have to add the dconf-editor to my apps and get it going from there.  No, wait, I had to get a copy of sni-qt:i386 as the update does not come from our repositories, but from Skype.  I understand why you would have thought it was coming automatically, however

Comment: I still think so since the latest package from the Skype web site includes (almost) the same "Depends" and "Recommends" lists as the package from Canonical Partner. Both recommend sni-qt.

Answer (score -1):

## Just , run this :

```
sh skype1404
```

Obviously, Download script before :

```
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/master/skype1404
    chmod u+x skype1404
```

---

**NOTE :** whatever HW plateform (32 or 64), it works `و الحمد لله`

Comment: that's a good patch for Skype, don't why people down vote you

Comment: @ucefkh : Because they don't like the last word which is "و الحمد لله" which means "Praise be to ALLAH" . And it is so logic because Allah said in Coran :"وَإِذَا ذُكِرَ اللَّهُ وَحْدَهُ اشْمَأَزَّتْ قُلُوبُ الَّذِينَ لَا يُؤْمِنُونَ بِالْآخِرَةِ ۖ وَإِذَا ذُكِرَ الَّذِينَ مِن دُونِهِ إِذَا هُمْ يَسْتَبْشِرُونَ" ==> " And when Allah is mentioned alone, the hearts of those who do not believe in the Hereafter shrink with aversion, but when those [worshipped] other than Him are mentioned, immediately they rejoice."  .

Comment: @ucefkh : <FOLLOW>... anywhere, Anywhere, WE have a proverb in arabic said :" إذا أنت أكرمت الكريم ملكته وإن أنت أكرمت اللئيم تمردا ." ==> TRANSLATE =>"Be generous to a generous person and you'd win him, be generous to a mean person and he'd rebel on you." Therefore, Don't care to them

Comment: :)
 الحمد لله
ALl praise to Allah

Comment: خوك من تونس . مرحبا

Comment: خوك من المغرب مرحبا

Comment: do you have any email ? mine is kh@01tek.com

Comment: Welcome dear Youssef Khouidi3e