# Can not access skype on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, skype

I have installed skype on my laptop (Ubuntu) yesterday...

It was working properly...

Today morning I re-installed Ubuntu completely...

Now it is creating trouble...

When I am trying to login it is showing **can't access skype account**

Should I change some proxy settings in that?

I have not done anything earlier but it was working properly..

When I tried to run

```
  sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin
```

in terminal it is showing:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 

E: Unable to locate package skype 
E: Unable to locate package skype-bin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Skype can't connect][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505581/skype-cant-connect

Comment: @WolfF. this is not quite a duplicate because that was problem for that particular day.... please try to help me!!

Comment: Which version of Skype you're using?

Comment: @WolfF. version 4.3

Comment: And What this command says `skype -version`?

Comment: @KasiyA :  it is not saying anything.. i have removed everything and installing again now.... but when  i tried sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin it is saying as i mentioned abbove

Comment: As I said you are using proxy on Ubuntu and you need to [set your proxy to work on apt-get update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy)

Comment: @KasiyA :  i am trying donadony's answer... first two steps are fine but i did not understand third step

Comment: You don't need step 3 there. just run `sudo apt-get update` again. And then follow How to install skype 4.3?

Comment: @KasiyA : Yes Yes// I got it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to [activate the Canonical Partner repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner).

Comment: i tried that... it is not working

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Can you please try to install skype in a terminal window using `sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin`, and paste the exact resulting output here by editing your question.

Comment: yes.. i edited the question... it is saying W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages 407 Proxy Authentication Required

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Yes, but that's out of context. I meant the complete output.

Comment: Ok... i will do that now..

Comment: it is saying... 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skype
E: Unable to locate package skype-bin

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Which makes me think that you did not activate Canonical Partner.

Comment: Yes... I did not do at that time.. i could not even realize... Now it is working properly.... Thank you so much :)