# installing skype

Tags: skype

I have recently like many received a notification from skype to upgrade my version of skype (which is no more working anyway). I have followed all the steps on the website - then on ubuntu BUT still does not work. I have deleted the previous version (and the icon has been removed from the bar). pleease help me! I need to skype with my old mum who lives abroad and has just been for a surgery...can some one assist? please do note that I am not an IT expert...but can type commands when they are clear. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Before we can do anything to help you, you need to mention what goes wrong. Any errors or other things it tells you when you try to install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Skype 4.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Answer (score 5):

First remove the previous version of skype

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then download skype from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/):

and install it

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-package-name
```

for instance:

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) for more details.

Comment: The [link suggested above for more details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) discourages to retrieve the [package from the skype website](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/).  Quote: "It is highly recommended to use the package provided in the Canonical partner repository, not the one distributed from the Skype website. This is how installing via a Ubuntu repository guarantees that the file downloaded and installed is the same one distributed from a Ubuntu repository. However, downloading the file via http doesn't guarantee this outcome."