# How do I install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-center, skype

I tried to download [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) and the latest version it said was Ubuntu 12.04 so I downloaded that. It opened in a Software Center with an install button. I clicked the install button and it went to 10% and just reverted back to an install button. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510699/installing-skype) but it gave an error:

```
chloe@chloe-latitude-d430:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for chloe: 
Selecting previously unselected package skype:i386.
(Reading database ... 207595 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking skype:i386 (4.3.0.37-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3).
...    
dpkg: error processing package skype:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
```

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/488062/276841) but it gave an error:

```
chloe@chloe-latitude-d430:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried the 2nd suggestion:

```
chloe@chloe-latitude-d430:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install skype
skype:i386 is already the newest version (4.3.0.37-1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I saw [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/488068/276841), but after I added 'Canonical Partners' in Software & Updates, I searched for Skype in Ubuntu Software and it didn't come up. Only 'spreedme' came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Skype in Ubuntu 16.04, run these commands in terminal one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

NOTE: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` is only for 64-bit system and not for 32-bit system. Also, if you get an error of missing dependencies, run `sudo apt-get -f install` from terminal.

Open Skype from Unity Dash. Then agree to Skype terms of use and Skype privacy policy. Next, sign in with your Microsoft account or Skype name. Then you're ready to use Skype!

**Helpful Links**

[How to install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-skype-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Yeah but that comes from the answer I referenced (http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3/488062#488062) and the 2nd line is for 64bit Ubuntu and my computer is a 32bit computer.

Comment: You should do `sudo apt-get -f install` to satisfy missing dependencies as suggested in the terminal output.

Comment: It will satisfy the missing dependencies first and will then install Skype.

Comment: I recommend you to try it because it works most of the time. I had also installed Skype after doing it(though I had a 64-bit system).