# Using skype 4.3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype

I am trying to install and use Skype 4.3 in ubuntu 14.04 (I upgraded both recently). I kept gettign the "skype can't connect" error so I followed the instructions here to the letter:

[How to install Skype 4.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

This works for the **first** skype use, but when I quit skype and run it again, I get the same (4.2) screen with the same "skype can't connect" error.

I can bypass the error by deleting my .Skype directory, but I have to do this prior to **every single** skype run.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I don't understand why a 4.2 error message window would show up anymore. I purged 4.2 using apt-get autoremove and apt-get purge and so forth.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get purge skype*` then delete old `rm -rf ~/.Skype` folder, next try installing [install skype 4.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3) as again.

Comment: thanks, but I have done this repeatedly! it works for the first run, but once the new .Skype folder is created the error returns.

Comment: Update: The problem cleared itself up eventually for me. I cannot see how it happened.

Comment: I kept trying to delete the `~/.skype` folder and it kept telling me that it did not exist... until I put a capital 'S' to the name. Ha! Ha! Total Unix geek here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve change the skype version to last version that time: 4.2.0.13-1_i386.deb , in fact by repository is more precise but I guess that have a error in any list of repo.
 Unfortunately  now have other problem with the sound, a noise in line, maybe the pulse audio, so... I wait answers too ;)

Comment: latest skype version is `skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`