# i have install skype but it's not launching

Tags: software-installation, skype

```
dpkg: considering removing skype-bin in favour of skype ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of skype-bin (--auto-deconfigure will help):
 skype depends on skype-bin
  skype-bin is to be removed.

dpkg: regarding skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb containing skype:
 skype conflicts with skype-bin
  skype-bin (version 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing skype
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

Comment: okay, uninstall and reinstall skype?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You should provide more than just an error message (circumstances, environment, what you tried so far...) Also see: http://www.askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, ([original link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3))

**Step 1:** Remove previous version.

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Step 2: Install Skype.

**For 32-bit OS:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

**For 64-bit OS:**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

*It is Important if you installed older version of Skype on your Ubuntu, Clear the old Skype folder. Then clear that by using:*

```
cd ~ && rm -r .Skype
```

Comment: This worked for me.