# How to install skype in ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Tags: 12.04, skype

I am trying to install Skype on Ubuntu 12.02.05. However, I get an error message:

```
rails@rails-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb 
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for rails: 
dpkg: error processing skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
rails@rails-desktop:~/Downloads$
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Skype 4.2 not supported any more. [install skype 4.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Comment: Then which version of skype to be used in ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: can us end me the link

Comment: at the end of first comment [install skype 4.3] or click [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/488062/283843)

Comment: sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  throwing error                                                                dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Comment: no problem continue and follow next steps

Comment: also it seems like your's "sudo" library has wrong permission
you can fix it by: sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/sudo

Comment: Why do you want to install Microsoft Skype? If you just want to chat and video-call you should use [jitsi](http://jitsi.org) ;)

Answer (score 1):

dpkg fails because cannot found the file, are you sure that you have download Skype at *~/Downloads* ?

Besides that, I recommend to use package manager like *apt* or *aptitude* (or if you prefer a graphic utilit *Ubuntu Sofware Center*).

```
# add repository
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

# update packages list and install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Source and more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

**EDIT**: removed add i386 as @gertvdijk suggested!