# Cannot install skype after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, skype

After upgrading to 14.10 Skype was removed from my installed packages. When trying to install I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype : Depends: skype-bin
```

I've attempted installing with apt-get, the deb from Skype, and the software center with no luck.  I've tried several methods including the ones listed here:

[How to install Skype 4.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3)

Thank you for any help

Comment: Try to install both `skype` and `skype-bin`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i  have got similar problem... please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/541012/can-not-access-skype-on-ubuntu

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I did try that with no luck. It says it's missing libqtwebkit4:i386.

Comment: @AndrewSmith: So install that package too then.

Comment: What is the output of running these two commands: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` AND `dpkg --print-architecture`?

Comment: i386 and amd64 respectively.

Comment: I'm assuming that means you have run sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 right?

Comment: Yes Run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and `sudo apt-get update` and follwo the installation from skype 4.3 link.

Comment: Still not working for me.  Just yields a bunch of missing :i386 packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same, and that's what helped me:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php5-trusty.list`

Than remove the hashes (#) re-enable that PPA which were disabled by updating system

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: You rock!  This fixed my issue!  :)

Comment: You're welcome. Updating from 14.04 to 14.10 made it.

Comment: Nailed it! Their packages on their site only supports 12.10

Answer (score 0):

I just have had same issue, And run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype-bin
wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

And thats it, my skype has started like a charm. :)