# Skype on Ubuntu 14.10 can't be installed after upgrade deleted it

Tags: skype, dependencies, 14.10

I was on Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday, and upgrade with `do-release-upgrade`. Today, Skype isn't installed anymore.

Here is the error I get when installing through the .deb:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 446199 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking skype (4.3.0.37-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
  Package libqtwebkit4:i386 is not installed.
 skype depends on libpulse0; however:
  Package libpulse0:i386 is not installed.
 skype depends on libasound2-plugins; however:

dpkg: error processing package skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.10.20140925-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.8-1ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
```

And if I try to use the partner repo:

```
$ sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I `sudo apt-get -f install` and try to reinstall the .deb, I end up with this error:

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4
```

Comment: Did you enable Canonical partners in Software Sources? See: [Install Skype On Ubuntu 14.10/14.04/12.04 | Unixmen](http://www.unixmen.com/install-skype-ubuntu-14-1014-0412-04/)

Comment: @blade19899 I did, edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Give this a try: http://askubuntu.com/a/488062/36315

Comment: @blade19899 already did :(

Comment: [Fix Skype Not Working In Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail \[For Users With Proprietary Nvidia Or AMD Drivers\] ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fix-skype-not-working-in-ubuntu-1304.html). Long shot, but still a shot.

Comment: you can go to 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3

Comment: @blade19899 the issue is that skype isn't installed.

Comment: It was a `Long shot, but still a shot.` :)

Comment: please post the output of `dpkg -l|grep -i skype`

Comment: I'm assuming you tried: `sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit4:i386 libpulse0 libasound2-plugins`?

Comment: @blade19899 here is what it says: http://pastie.margaine.com/a32a8140-ec0d-403f-a05d-f10c12ad7988

Answer (score 2):

So, after purging everything, as @Jan suggested, the following still didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

I had the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Turns out I needed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin
```

And everything worked out of the box.

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

I assue that after trying to install from the .deb, you had a half-installed package lingering. To get rid of everything skype-related, use `sudo apt-get purge skype` in a terminal window (or if that fails, use `dpkg -P skype`).

Installing from the partner repo should work then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue. See here: http://pastie.margaine.com/b60e1055-e16d-46a1-9152-5744f723c77e

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question.

Comment: I actually just found the solution. I needed `sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin`. `sudo apt-get install skype` wasn't enough. Yes, the partner repository was enabled :)

Comment: Then you must have setup apt to not install dependencies by default...

Comment: It has never failed before, and I haven't changed anything. Do you know where I might see this setting? It installed many other dependencies like libqtwebkit, so I don't think that's it.