# trouble in installing mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i am trying to install mysqlworkbench in my ubuntu using

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64.deb.3
```

but getting following errors

```
(Reading database ... 188276 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-workbench-community 6.0.9-1ubu1310(using mysql-                workbench-   community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64.deb.3) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql-workbench-community ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
mysql-workbench-community depends on libctemplate2; however:
Package libctemplate2 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9); however:
Version of libglib2.0-0 on system is 2.32.4-0ubuntu1.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2); however:
Version of libglibmm-2.4-1c2a on system is 2.32.0-0ubuntu1.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
Package libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0); however:
Package libpango-1.0-0 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
Package libpangocairo-1.0-0 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7); however:
Package libpcrecpp0 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libtinyxml2.6.2; however:
Package libtinyxml2.6.2 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libzip2 (>= 0.10); however:
Package libzip2 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on python-paramiko; however:
Package python-paramiko is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on python-pysqlite2; however:
Package python-pysqlite2 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-workbench-community (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: It may be easier to install using `apt-get install mysql-workbench`, however the version you get will be 6.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going at it the wrong way. You are having dependency issues trying to install MySQL Workbench 6.0.9, when you could easily install MySQL Workbench 6.0.8 in Ubuntu 14.04 from the Ubuntu Software Center or from the terminal using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: i tried but  Ubuntu Software Center not displaying  MySQL Workbench in software lists

Comment: Try searching for MySQL Workbench in the Ubuntu Software Center by using its package name: *mysql-workbench*. mysql-workbench is provided by the **universe** repository in Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 and 14.10.

Comment: hurray it worked..thank you so much :) i had been struggling from past 4 hours

Comment: can u please mention the package name for skype in Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: [How to install Skype 4.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3) -- the latest version of Skype. There are two ways to install Skype, from the Canonical Partner Repository or simply download Skype and double-click the Skype file to install it, which is the way I did it.

Comment: thank u ...i got it by Right clicking on the Skype-package i have downloaded and then opening it with ubuntu software center