# Can't install Skype, unmet dependencies

Tags: skype, dependencies

I could not install skype

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libllvm3.5:i386 (>= 1:3.5~+rc3) but it is not going to be installed 
skype : Depends: skype-bin 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: also useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php5-trusty.list`

Than remove the hashes (#) re-enable that PPA which were probably disabled by system

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install skype`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the unmet dependencies of skype package, run the following command.

$ sudo apt-get -f install

Source: https://www.itsmearunchandel.co.in/linux/ubuntu/install-skype-on-ubuntu-18-04.html