# Why is Skype not available from Australian software repository?

Tags: skype

I followed the instructions on [How to install Skype 4.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3) however I was unable to install Skype until I went into Software Sources and chose "Main Server".

Is this going to be a common issue? I've switched back to the Australian server now but I hope I'm not going to be toggling that setting all the time.

Here is the output from `apt-cache policy skype`

```
skype:
  Installed: 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidate: 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Actually we may have solved it in a roundabout way. I took out multiverse and the 'Canonical Partners' links that were pointing to' archive' and went back to having one source: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/. I now see after letting everything regenerate in the Software Centre GUI that Skype is listed and I can bring up 'More Info' without getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is simply that I was pointing at some deprecated repositories. Check under 'Software Sources' in the Software Centre and untick all but the 'main' repository options on the 'Ubuntu Software' tab, removing any 'partner' repositories on the 'Other Software' tab. Be sure to let the Software Centre do its update (or run `sudo apt-get update`) and the list should now be correct and include Skype.

Use the list of mirrors at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AustralianTeam/LocalAptMirrors if you have lost your original repository URL.