# Unmet dependencies while installing Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, skype

I followed [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3#comment692184_488068). I have tried both method multiple times. But i ended with following error. I am struggling since last night. Can you help me please. 
Thanks

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

skype: Depends: skype-bin but it is a virtual package
unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed

Comment: Can you add the command used to install skype to the question.